# nl2br to display textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I am implementing a contact form. When the user submits the form, all input is validated and stored in a session. It is then forwarded to a page that informs the user of a successfully posting of the comment, displaying the data entered.

The trouble I am having is that all new lines are not being displyed correctly as breaks using `nl2br()`.

User input:

`<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="50" id="comments" tabindex="5" title="comments">
                <?php echo isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : ''; ?>`

when validated...

`$_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['comments'];`

forwarded on to contact-sent page and then appended to the string to display

`$forwardString = "<h2>New Website Comment: </h2><h3>" . $cEmail . "</h3><p>" . $cComment . "</p>";`

Then displayed:

`echo nl2br($forwardString);`

Where do I implement the nl2br() function?

Example input:

```
Just a test to verify contact works correctly.

We should see two line breaks here.
One line break here
```

Currently yields:

```
Just a test to verify contact works correctly.We should see two line breaks here.One line break here
```

Comment: When outputting to a textarea, you don't need `nl2br` at all. Maybe `htmlspecialchars`, but that's another question...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo nl2br(stripslashes($forwardString));
```

You could be possibly escaping the string twice so the \n becomes \n

Comment: Thanks for your replies...@Diego - out put is not to a textarea - but input read from a textarea - stored in a session and used via the session variable and output as html.  @CodeBird - 

`echo nl2br(stripslashes($forwardString));`

Made no difference, same output as html.

Comment: Sorted Doh! I have a specific function to remove email injection on input and this removed the new line characters.